# Плечевая — этимология

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Плечевая — это проститутка, которая обслуживает клиентов на трассе. Почему именно плечевая? Каким боком здесь *плечо*? Слово жаргонное, поэтому не знаю, корректно ли ставить вопрос о происхождении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это жаргон дальнобойщиков. *Плечо трассы* - промежуток дороги между заправками. Соответственно, такие пассажирки едут на протяжении *плеча*, до следующей заправки.

https://gubdaily.ru/blog/lifestyle/interesnoe/pochemu-prostitutok-na-trasse-nazyvayut-plechevymi-rossijskie-dalnobojshhiki-chestno-otvetili-na-samye-populyarnye-voprosy-o-svoej-professii/

Answer (score 1):

Потому ,что плечо у водителя дальнобоя левое загорает ,а у проститут.правое.Вот их и называли плечевыми и сразу по загару можно было узнать кто перед тобой